# Jekyll 3.0 run on localhost:4000 error

Tags: jekyll

Recently， I upgrade my jekyll server from 2.5 to 3.0 , However, it occur a problem:

i render my page on gitpage that is very successful, but when i render it on my local jekyll server, there has a error

my every post's route is   `/category/YYYY/MM/DD/postName.html` (The category is chinese)

At the git page it was no problem

but when i use the localhost server , when i cilck these post anchors , It show no find this html file , and redirect to the 404.html

On local anchors's href such as `http://localhost:4000/%E6%8A%80%E6%9C%AF/2016/04/04/array-function.html`

and on the git page the href is `http://numerhero.github.io/%E6%8A%80%E6%9C%AF/2016/04/04/array-function.html`

it was my gitpage address , no any problem : http://numerhero.github.io

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Install Bundler `gem install bundler`
2. Navigate to your project's root `cd path/to/project`
3. Run `bundle init` (will create a `Gemfile`)
4. Edit your Gemfile:

   ```
   source 'https://rubygems.org'
   gem 'github-pages'
   ```
5. Run `bundle install`
6. Run `bundle update` (once and awhile)
7. Serve Jekyll with Bundler: `bundle exec jekyll serve`

Done!

Your problem must be related to your local dependencies, which must be different than GitHub Pages'. With [Bundler](//bundler.io), a dependency manager, you will make sure you have `github-pages` and [all it's dependencies](https://pages.github.com/versions/) installed locally.

Run `bundle update` once and awhile to make sure you have the last versions installed.

Read more about upgrading Jekyll 2 to 3 here:

http://blog.virtuacreative.com.br/upgrade-jekyll-2-to-3-gh-pages.html

Comment: i try your method

however, when i run the bundle install

it show me this error: 

`Undefined local variable or method 'gigem' for Gemfile. Bundler cannot continue`

Comment: My bad! Terrible typo! it's not `gigem 'github-pages'`, just `gem 'github-pages'`! I'm really sorry! I updated the answer. Please, fix it on your Gemfile and try again! Let me know how it goes, yeah?

Comment: Yes ，I  try your method again with change the gigem to gem , but It give me a new error:
`Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ECONNRESET: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/gems/terminal-table-1.5.2.gem)`

And

`An error occurred while installing RedCloth (4.2.9), and Bundler cannot
continue`

Comment: Hmm.. I guess it might be you don't have OpenSSL installed locally. In the Gemfile, change the protocol from `https` to `http`. But I'm not 100% sure this is the source of this last error. Don't worry, I'll be glad to help you out :)

Comment: Ok , then what should I do?

Comment: In your Gemfile, replace `source 'https://rubygems.org' ` for `source 'http://rubygems.org'` and then run the steps 5 to 7 (described on the answer).